# Javascript - loop through the same array more than once

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

How do I get the below for loop statement to go through my array more than once?

```
var clients = new Array("client1", "client2", "client3", "client4", "client5");

var indexCounter;
var holmesminutes = 0;
for (indexCounter = 0; indexCounter < clients.length; indexCounter++) {
    holmesminutes = holmesminutes + 15;
    document.write(clients[indexCounter] + " testroom " + holmesminutes +"<br>");
}
```

Comment: why can you just run it again?

Comment: BTW, don't use `new Array`, use an array literal.

Comment: Is your issue that it only goes through one index of the array, or it goes through the WHOLE array once?

Comment: If you want it to run, say 2 times, look at agconti's answer below. If you want it to run infinite time, use a while(true){} block and have something inside your while(true){} block to escape an infinite loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put another loop around the loop.

```
for (var repeatCounter = 0; repeatCounter < 5; repeatCounter++) {
    for (indexCounter = 0; indexCounter < clients.length; indexCounter++) {
        holmesminutes = holmesminutes + 15;
        document.write(clients[indexCounter] + " testroom " + holmesminutes +"<br>");
    }
}
```

To stop all the loops when `holmesminutes` reaches 315:

```
for (var repeatCounter = 0; repeatCounter < 5 && holmesminutes < 315; repeatCounter++) {
    for (indexCounter = 0; indexCounter < clients.length && holmesminutes < 315; indexCounter++) {
        holmesminutes = holmesminutes + 15;
        document.write(clients[indexCounter] + " testroom " + holmesminutes +"<br>");
    }
}
```

As you see, you can put any condition you want in the test clause of `for`, it doesn't have to refer only to the iteration variable.

Comment: I just have to know -- what part of this isn't totally obvious? You clearly know how to write loops, so what was it that you didn't get?

Comment: I've only just started to learn JavaScript I've never put a loop around another loop before. I've only just figured out when I need the loop to stop. Is there a way to stop the loop after the variable "holmesminutes" gets to 315? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What about other programming languages you've used before? Don't they have loops similar to JS?

Comment: I don't know any other programming languages, I've used c# a bit but part from that, I haven't done any others. I've only learnt html and CSS so far.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that because you were so specific, you didn't mean you just started programming.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a [while loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp):

```
var clients = new Array("client1","client2","client3","client4","client5");
var indexCounter;
var holmesminutes =0;
_i= 0;

while (_i < 2) {
    for(indexCounter = 0; indexCounter<clients.length;indexCounter++)
     {
     holmesminutes = holmesminutes + 15;
     document.write(clients[indexCounter] + " testroom " +  holmesminutes + "<br>");
     _i++;
     }
}
```