# apache poi - looping the same array more than once

Tags: java, apache-poi

[JavaScript = loop through the array more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205449/javascript-loop-through-the-same-array-more-than-once)

I tried to follow the code from the link but still my array wont loop more than once.

What I am trying to do is I want to loop the days repeatedly based on the total number of the year in verticle column. the output that I am getting is

Days

SU

SU

SU

SU

SU

SU

SU

I am sorry to ask such question, because I am a beginner in java and using apache poi. thanks

```
String[] days = { "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA", "SU", "MO" };

int boundary = 0;

    for (int repeatcounter = 1; repeatcounter <= days.length && boundary <= 365; repeatcounter++) {

        for (int i = 1; i < days.length && boundary < 365; i++) {

            boundary = boundary + 1;

            Row row1 = sheet.getRow(repeatcounter);

            Cell cell = row1.createCell(1);

            cell.setCellValue(days[i - 1]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator `%` as follows:

```
String[] days = { "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA", "SU", "MO" };
for(int i = 0; i < someNumber; i++)
    System.out.println(days[i % 7]);
}
```

Output:

```
TU
WE
TH
FR
SA
SU
MO
TU
WE
TH
FR
SA
SU
MO
TU
WE
TH
...
```